# Python If Statment

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, if-statement

I have some problem here

```
ress = []

    number_tag = number_of_starttags + number_of_endtags
    CTTD = words_count + (0.5 * link_words) + number_tag - number_tag_break
    if  words_count + link_number  == 0:
        CTTD == 0
    else:
        CTTD
    res = [words_count, link_words, number_tag, number_tag_break, CTTD]
    ress.append(res)
```

but the output is not generated as expected.
I want to be when `word_count` + `link_words` amounted to 0 then `CTTD` will immediately be 0.

What I get now is CTTD still be calculated according to the initial formulation, does not care whether WORD_COUNT + link_word = 0.

So how to get the right output?

Comment: What does the `else: CTTD` part do?

Comment: i guess CTTD True/1

Comment: Also what is `CTTD == 0` meant to do?

Comment: read @jakobs answer

Answer (score 3):

```
if  words_count + link_number  == 0:
    CTTD == 0
else:
    CTTD
```

Neither of these clauses do anything.

`CTTD == 0` is a comparison expression, which evaluates to `True` or `False`, and then discards that value.

`CTTD` is an expression, which evaluates to the value of `CTTD`, and then discards that value.

In Python, `=` is used for assignment.

Comment: I want to make it a requirement if the number words_count + link_words is 0 then CTTD would also be worth 0. If not 0 then CTTD will calculate the appropriate formula is written. so what i have to do?

Comment: You already have two very good answers to that question. You have to use assignment (`=`) to assign values to variables. You cannot use comparison (`==`) to assign values to variables.

Answer (score 2):

you need to assign, which is `=`

```
ress = []

number_tag = number_of_starttags + number_of_endtags
CTTD = words_count + (0.5 * link_words) + number_tag - number_tag_break
if  words_count + link_number  == 0:
    CTTD = 0   #  <----------------  HERE IS YOUR PROBLEM
else:
    CTTD
res = [words_count, link_words, number_tag, number_tag_break, CTTD]
ress.append(res)
```

Comment: The CTTD after else is also wrong.  What is it you are trying to do?  CTTD is the name of a variable.  You aren't assigning it a value or using it in a statement, so what is it you think is going on ?

Comment: I'm pointing out his error.  He wanted to know why it wasn't being assigned.  I don't believe in solving every single error he has, cause then we play the "gotcha game" with people troubleshooting why I didn't fix all his errors.  He want's to know why CTTD wasn't becoming `0` and I showed him why.